# Nativescript angular 2 call Function On page load every time

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-nativescript

I want to execute a piece of code every time a new the page in navigated to. I am using the `<page-router-outlet>`.

As mention [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-navigation.html#lifecycle-hooks-and-component-caching), while using page-router-outlet the component is cached. So when it is navigated back into view no `Init` lifecycle events of angular 2 are executed.

I tied using just the , which does not cache the component and as a result call the `Init` Lifecycle events. But using it exits the app when I press the Hardware back button.

Comment: You can export that function into a separate service, import it into every component you need and just call it by `ngOnInit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site you linked to also mentions this: "What you can do is inject Page inside your component and attach to page navigation events (for example navigatedFrom) and do the cleanup there." Those events are listed [here](http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_page_.page.html#on), especially the "navigatedTo" event seems relevant for your usecase.